# How can I read properties from an object which is a property from another object?

Tags: php, json

```
stdClass Object
(
[kind] => youtube#channelListResponse
[etag] => "Fznwjl6JEQdo1MGvHOGaz_YanRU/AwtUznqL5IWQ_LGBo6hPktZlciI"
[pageInfo] => stdClass Object
    (
        [totalResults] => 1
        [resultsPerPage] => 1
    )

[items] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [kind] => youtube#channel
                [etag] => "Fznwjl6JEQdo1MGvHOGaz_YanRU/89K2C_1kE4Ku8LvtzDJQlV5_e2I"
                [id] => UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw
                [snippet] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [title] => PewDiePie
                        [description] => I make videos.
                        [publishedAt] => 2010-04-29T10:54:00.000Z
                        [thumbnails] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [default] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [url] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l79FVckie4j9WT-4cEW6iu3gPd4GivQf_XNSWg=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo
                                        [width] => 88
                                        [height] => 88
                                    )

                                [medium] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [url] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l79FVckie4j9WT-4cEW6iu3gPd4GivQf_XNSWg=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo
                                        [width] => 240
                                        [height] => 240
                                    )

                                [high] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [url] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l79FVckie4j9WT-4cEW6iu3gPd4GivQf_XNSWg=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo
                                        [width] => 800
                                        [height] => 800
                                    )

                            )

                        [localized] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [title] => PewDiePie
                                [description] => I make videos.
                            )

                        [country] => US
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

How can I get the value of (e.g. url of the high stdClass object)?

Should I have to create first an array or can I access directly to this value? I don't know how to get the value of an object which is property from another object.

Thank in advance!

Comment: Please show what you've already tried, along with the desired result, and the actual result.

Comment: Also, there are 3 `url` values in that `thumbnails` object.

Comment: Yes, and how can I access to the **high** value? @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case:

```php
echo $myObject->items[0]->id; //Outputs UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw

//or

echo $myObject->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->default->url; //Outputs: https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l79FVckie4j9WT-4cEW6iu3gPd4GivQf_XNSWg=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo
```

Object attributes must be refered with **arrow (->)** and array elements with **brackets ([])**.
`items` is an array, as you can see in your output.

In this example, I'm reading `items` from the main object (`$myObject`), the first index from items array (0), then it's property `id`;

Comment: @itranger  If this solves your problem, then you really should edit your question, because this answer does _not_ answer what was asked.

Comment: @itranger  I mean, you're still explicitly asking for "url of the high stdClass object".  As I said in my comment on your question, questions should really show your attempted code (you are expected to show some effort in solving your problem), the current result (including any exact error messages), and the desired result. This helps provide more accurate answers, and often provide answers in a more timely manner.

Comment: @PatrickQ Just chill bro. My intention was just point him the right way. I've included the requested example...